# implementing table using variables to a html email

Tags: html, email, html-table

I figured out how to send a html email, this part is already done. What I can't figure out is how to implement a table into the email. I can create a html file from the table (which is created from a list of tuples), but I can't put it in the file.
The part of code is below, under that you can find

```
def mail():

    html = f"""
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>Hej, <br>
        </p>
        <p><br>
        </p>
        <p>wpisz proszę zamówienie:<br>
          <br>
        </p>
        <p>Data: {dzisiaj}<br>
          Klient: {nazwa_klienta}<br>
          Incoterms: {incoterms}</p>
          <table>
          {tabela}
          </table><br>
          <p>Opis: {atrybuty_zamówienie["opis"]}<br>
          <p>Atrybuty:<br>
          PE: {atrybuty_zamówienie["PE"]}<br>
          Gilza: {atrybuty_zamówienie["gilza"]}<br>
          Korona: {atrybuty_zamówienie["korona"]}<br>
          Max średnica: {atrybuty_zamówienie["max średnica"]}<br>
          Min średnica: {atrybuty_zamówienie["min średnica"]}<br>
          Pakowanie: {atrybuty_zamówienie["pakowanie"]}<br>
          Nawinięcie: {atrybuty_zamówienie["nawinięcie"]}<br>
        </p>
        <div class="moz-signature">-- <br>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <title></title>
          Pozdrawiam / Best regards
          <div class="moz-signature">
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0cm">Mateusz Cyman <br>
              <strong>Export Manager</strong><br>
              Tel. my number </p>
            <br>
            my company data
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>""" 
    
  
    email_from = 'myemail@myemail.com'
    password = 'xxxxxx'
    email_to = 'mysecondemail@myemail.com'
    
    email_message = MIMEMultipart()
    email_message['From'] = email_from
    email_message['To'] = email_to
    email_message['Subject'] = f'Zamówienie {nazwa_klienta} - {dzisiaj}'

    email_message.attach(MIMEText(html, "html"))
    # Convert it as a string
    email_string = email_message.as_string()
    
    
    
    with smtplib.SMTP('myemail@server.com', 25) as server:
        server.login(email_from, password)
        server.sendmail(email_from, email_to, email_string)
        server.quit()
```

and here is the part for a table. The list changes depending on many variables.

```
zamowienie = [('papier bielony', 'ip', '35g', '+ ', '10g PE', 'szerokość', '300mm'), ('papier niebielony', 'stora', '45g', '+ ', '10g PE', 'szerokość', '550mm')]
tabela = tabulate(zamowienie, tablefmt='html')
```

I tried using tabulate, but I only succeeded in creating html table, I don't know how to implement it into already existing email. I also tried putting a whole table into variable (which it is in a current state), but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.